# cant export gazebo_model_path

Tags: ros

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I was following using urdf with gazebo tutorial but as i try to export the path of robot urdf to gazebo path by using command:   `export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=/home/user/catkin_ws/src/` what i see inside gazebo is just the name of the path but no drop down arrow.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14249/cant-export-gazebo_model_path/) by [hari1234](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2771/hari1234/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 56 on 2016-08-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If the path is displayed empty, it means that either the directory really is empty, or the model structure within the path is not recognized by Gazebo. The [model structure](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=model_structure&cat=build_robot) should be the following:

```
/home/user/catkin_ws/src/
└── model_name
    ├── model.config
    └── model.sdf
```

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1